##[warning]Task 'AWS Shell Script' version 1 (AWSShellScript@1) is dependent on a Node version (10)
My Azure DevOps Pipeine getting below warning:
##[warning]Task 'Amazon ECR Push' version 1 (ECRPushImage@1) is dependent on a Node version (10) that is end-of-life. Contact the extension owner for an updated version of the task. Task maintainers should review Node upgrade guidance: https://aka.ms/node-runner-guidance

My Pipeline tasks:
     - task: AWSShellScript@1
     displayName: Docker build ${{ appService.name }}
      inputs:
        regionName: '${{ parameters.ecrRegion }}'
        scriptType: 'inline'
        inlineScript: |
          aws ecr get-login-password --region ${{ parameters.ecrRegion }}| docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $(ecrURL)
          echo -e "FROM ${{ parameters.openJDKImage }} \nRUN mkdir /artifact && apk add openssl \nCOPY ${{ appService.name }}-$(JAR_SNAPSHOT_VERSION).jar /artifact/service.jar \nCMD [\"/bin/sh\", \"-c\", \"java -jar /artifact/service.jar\"]" > Dockerfile | docker build . -t $(ecrURL)/${{ appService.ecrRepo }}:$(VERSION)-$(COMMIT)
        disableAutoCwd: true
        workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
- task: ECRPushImage@1
        displayName: Push ${{ appService.name }} image to DEV ECR
        inputs:
          regionName: '${{ parameters.ecrRegion }}'
          sourceImageName: '$(ecrURL)/${{ appService.ecrRepo }}'
          sourceImageTag: '$(VERSION)-$(COMMIT)'
          repositoryName: '${{ appService.ecrRepo }}'
          pushTag: '$(VERSION)-$(COMMIT)'
          outputVariable: '$(ecrURL)/${{ appService.ecrRepo }}:$(VERSION)-$(COMMIT)'

We are using Azure DevOps default agents for pipeline runs.
i also tried to update the task to 2 but its not working.
Pls any one have the information, let me know.

Hi @brucewayne, have you checked the answers below? Since it's a known issue in AWS and haven't been resolved, it would be better to use AWS CLI in the pipeline.

I used AWS CLI in the pipeline and its working fine for me.

Hi @brucewayne, it's great to know AWS CLI works for you. Since it can resolve the issue, it's suggested that you could accept nacho's answer below. So that others who has the same question can know the solution clearly.

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT Done

@brucewayne
The warning error you are seeing is a known issue with the AWS Toolkit for Azure DevOps extension and you can follow discussions: ECRPushImage warning in Azure Devops due to Node10 dependency

##[warning]Task 'Amazon ECR Push' version 1 (ECRPushImage@1) is dependent on a Node version (10) that is end-of-life. Contact the extension owner for an updated version of the task. Task maintainers should review Node upgrade guidance: https://aka.ms/node-runner-guidance

If this becomes a significant problem, consider using alternative tasks, such as Bash@3 and Docker@2 and avoid using tasks from the extension, while this is been fixed.
I have tried a simple pipeline with Docker task:
The full yaml file is here: https://github.com/iheanacho-chukwu/aks-hellowebapi/blob/deploy-to-ecr/docker-task-aws.yml
- script: |
    echo "Logging in to AWS ECR"
    aws ecr get-login-password --region $(AWS_REGION) | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $(AWS_ACCOUNT_ID).dkr.ecr.$(AWS_REGION).amazonaws.com
  displayName: 'Login to AWS'
  env:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build and Push Docker Image
  inputs:
    repository: $(DOCKER_REPOSITORY)
    command: buildAndPush
    Dockerfile: Dockerfile
    tags: |
      $(TAG)


another one using entirely bash: https://github.com/iheanacho-chukwu/aks-hellowebapi/blob/deploy-to-ecr/push-docker-image-ecr-using-bash.yml
- script: |
    echo "Logging in to AWS ECR"
    aws ecr get-login-password --region $(AWS_REGION) | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $(AWS_ACCOUNT_ID).dkr.ecr.$(AWS_REGION).amazonaws.com
  displayName: 'Login to AWS'
  env:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

- script: |
    docker build -t $(DOCKER_REPOSITORY):$(TAG) .
    docker tag $(DOCKER_REPOSITORY):$(TAG) $(AWS_ACCOUNT_ID).dkr.ecr.$(AWS_REGION).amazonaws.com/$(DOCKER_REPOSITORY_NAME):$(TAG)
    docker push $(AWS_ACCOUNT_ID).dkr.ecr.$(AWS_REGION).amazonaws.com/$(DOCKER_REPOSITORY_NAME):$(TAG)
  displayName: 'Build and Push Docker Image using Bash Script'
  env:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

I passed my AWS credential as Azure DevOps variable group, so I dont have to hardcode to repo.


If I use your scripts, do they require AWS CLI and Docker as prerequisites? Are these tools already installed on Microsoft-hosted agents?

Azure DevOps already posted the announce about Remove Node 6 and Node 10 runners from Microsoft-hosted agents in 2022.

As mentioned by @nacho, this is a known issue in AWS. AWS is working on migrating to Node 16.

I like to acknowledge that we are aware of this problem. In our past attempts to address this, we got blocked by a shelljs related JS bundler issue which prevented us from updating azure-pipelines-task-lib. We are looking into this again and will post an update once we have more information.

This is the extension published by AWS and haven't been fixed. Based on the current situation, I would suggest you use AWS CLI in the pipeline directly instead of using the extension.
